logstash-logback-encoder: I hope to upload the `Number` to `ELK` from `MDC`, not `String`, but `MdcJsonProvider` unsupport it
I hope to upload the Number to ELK from MDC, not String, but MdcJsonProvider unsupport it.
MDC.put("cost-all", "1"); // unsupport Number, only support String

This will result in the inability to filter logs through the value range on Kibana.
see：
enter image description here
enter image description here
